# Dynamic List of Numbers through Hidden Rows

Tags: excel, list, rows, hidden

I have a list of items. I'd like to add a Line Item # to easily reference that list.

1. Part A
2. Part B
3. Part C

At times, I hide items on the list but I'd like to keep the Line Item flowing. If I hid the row that contains Part B it would hide the row inclusive of Column A which contains the Line Item.

1. Part A

"3". Part C

I'd like it to bypass the hidden row and dynamically update the line item to match the unhidden rows.

1. Part A
2. Part C

Doable in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can use `SUBTOTAL`:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103,$B$2:B2)
```

and copy down

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome. This works too well though. How would you change if I wanted to include a line break? Is there a way to skip empty rows?

Comment: @tackdetack to exclude empty rows use ```=IF(LEN(B2),SUBTOTAL(103,$B$2:B2),"")```. For line break I didn't understand what was meant. Can you show an example?

Comment: Amazing. This is perfect.